# Reading .csv stored in Azure Blob Storage from Excel

Tags: excel, csv, azure, blob, azure-storage

I've been able to create a storage account, then a container, than a blob storing a .csv file. I've successfully been able to download the .csv file from Azure itself and using Python as well via the azure-storage package. This is to confirm that external sources (i.e. Python) are able to import/export blobs. The .csv stores a numeric table with header in the first row.

The second step is to import the same data in Excel 2016. The steps that I'm following from Excel are:
New Query --> From Azure --> From Microsoft Azure Blob Storage --> provide  and  --> Navigator. From here, I can see that dataset.csv file in the container.

[image]

However, clicking the button "load" in the Navigator only allows to download the table in the previous picture in excel, and not the data stored in those files.

[image]

I've explored the add ons "Design" and "Query" to look for a button to download the data stored in those blobs but unsuccessfully.

**Question**: how to import the numberic data stored in one of the .csv in Azure Blobs listed in the Wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to import the data from the stored excel in the azure blob. You need edit the import data.

More details, you could refer to this image:

1.When you use query to query the information in the blob.  Click edit button.

[image]

2.Then you could click the binary to change the loaded value to your excel.

[image]

3.Then you could load the details excel data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the Import Data module loads data from a CSV or TSV file in Azure blob storage, a type guesser looks for categorical or numerical data in the source file, and represents the discovered type in the metadata for the new dataset.
However, you can override the results of the type guesser by editing the column attributes in the [Edit Metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn905986.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) module after the data has been loaded

For more information; You may refer to  this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674698.aspx).

Comment: I think that you indicating how to import data in Azure ML, but the question refers to Microsoft Excel.